# Click event on javascript based autocomplete/dropdown menu not closing properly

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, mootools

I created a script that simulates an autocomplete for an `<input type="text" />` by hiding/showing a `<ul>` that is positioned  with said input. Once the user clicks on the `<input type="text" />`, the `<ul>` will become visible and clickable, and will close when one of three conditions is met:

- User reclicks on the `<input type="text" />`
- User clicks on one of the options in the displayed `<ul>`
- User clicks on anything that is not related to this system

Thus far, I've gotten everything to work just fine. Unfortunately, I've run into a problem if there are two such "autocomplete" fields on the page. If the user opens one "autocomplete" interface, then clicks to open the other interface, the first/original one does not close as expected.

I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

```js
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  new autoComplete();
});
var autoComplete = new Class({
 options: {
  version:  '1.0',
  lastUpdate: '2016-06-27'
 },

 Implements: [Options,Events],
 initialize: function(options) {
  this.setOptions(options);
  
  $$('.autocomplete').each(function(acl) {
   acl.getChildren('ul li').each(function(li) {
    li.addEvent('click', function() {
     acl.getChildren('input[type=text]')[0].value = li.get('html');
     acl.getChildren('input[type=hidden]')[0].value = li.get('data-id');
     acl.getChildren('ul').addClass('hidden');
    });
   });
   
   acl.getChildren('input')[0].addEvents({
    click: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     
     var el = e.target;
     var val = el.value;
     var aul = el.getParent().getChildren('ul')[0];
     var str = '';
     
     aul.toggleClass('hidden');
     
     aul.getChildren().each(function(l) {
      str = l.get('html').toLowerCase();
      if (str.indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != 0) {
       l.addClass('hidden');
      } else {
       l.removeClass('hidden');
      }
     });
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     
     var el = e.target;
     var val = el.value;
     var aul = el.getParent().getChildren('ul')[0];
     var str = '';
     
     aul.removeClass('hidden');
     
     aul.getChildren().each(function(l) {
      str = l.get('html').toLowerCase();
      if (str.indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != 0) {
       l.addClass('hidden');
      } else {
       l.removeClass('hidden');
      }
     });
    }
   });
  });
  
  $(document.body).addEvent('click', function() {
   $$('.autocomplete ul').addClass('hidden');
  });
 }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}

.autocomplete ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.autocomplete ul li {
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}

.autocomplete ul li:first-child {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.autocomplete ul li:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Drk:</label>
    <div class="autocomplete">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <input type="hidden" />
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li data-id="drk1-Nito">Nito</li>
        <li data-id="drk1-Seath">Seath</li>
        <li data-id="drk1-FourKings">Four Kings</li>
        <li data-id="drk1-BedofChaos">Bed of Chaos</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-TheRotten">The Rotten</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-DukesDearFreja">Duke's Dear Freja</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-OldIronKing">Old Iron King</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-LostSinner">Lost Sinner</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Yhorm">Yhorm</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Aldritch">Aldritch</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Abysswatcher">Abyss Watcher</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Lothric">Lothric</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Bld:</label>
    <div class="autocomplete">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <input type="hidden" />
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li data-id="bld-ClericBeast">Cleric Beast</li>
        <li data-id="bld-FatherGascoigne">Father Gascoigne</li>
        <li data-id="bld-WitchesofHemwick">Witches of Hemwick</li>
        <li data-id="bld-VicarAmelia">Vicar Amelia</li>
        <li data-id="bld-ShadowsofYarhnam">Shadows of Yarhnam</li>
        <li data-id="bld-VacuousRom">Vacuous Rom</li>
        <li data-id="bld-TheOneReborn">The One Reborn</li>
        <li data-id="bld-Micolash">Micolash</li>
        <li data-id="bld-MergosWetnurse">Mergo's Wetnurse</li>
        <li data-id="bld-OldHunterGermaine">Old Hunter Germaine</li>
        <li data-id="bld-MoonPresence">Moon Presence</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is customary to include a minimal, complete and verifiable example in your question. As external sites go down, so does our ability to help you and others in the future.

Comment: Also, use the `blur` event to detect when an element has lost focus.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Modified question to add code as snippet as opposed to external site (wasn't aware stackoverflow had that option).

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tested the blur event, and while it works in that selecting the other input now closes the first one, it also has the unintended side effect of closing the options list when trying to select one, before an option is even selected.

Comment: Hmmmm. That makes it more tricky. When the autocomplete is open and something is clicked, if the click target is not a descendant of the open `.autocomplete`, close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `blur` event. Since it fires before `click` you could change that to `mousedown` and `touchstart` if you need mobile support. So your class could look like this:

(notice I cleaned up a bit and create now a new Class instance to each element, I see it more modular/independant like that)

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $$('.autocomplete').each(function(el) {
        new autoComplete(el);
    });
});
var autoComplete = new Class({
    options: {
        version: '1.0',
        lastUpdate: '2016-06-27'
    },
    Implements: [Options, Events],
    initialize: function(acl, options) {
        this.setOptions(options);
        var self = this;
        var ul = acl.getElement('ul');
        var lis = ul.getChildren('li');
        var input = acl.getElement('input');

        lis.addEvent('mousedown', function(e) {
            input.value = this.get('html');
            acl.getElement('input[type=hidden]').value = this.get('data-id');
            ul.addClass('hidden');
        });

        input.addEvents({
            mousedown: function(e) {
                ul.toggleClass('hidden');
                self.toggle(lis, this.value.toLowerCase());
            },
            keyup: function(e) {
                ul.removeClass('hidden');
                self.toggle(lis, this.value.toLowerCase());
            },
            blur: function(e) {
                ul.addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    },
    toggle: function(els, val) {
        els.each(function(el) {
            var str = el.get('html').toLowerCase();
            var match = str.indexOf(val) != -1;
            el.toggleClass('hidden', !match);
        });
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1on4kpj0/

If you need touch support you could do like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1on4kpj0/1/

Comment: Never occurred to me that it may be easier to manage if the class was attached to the elements, as opposed to the other way around.

Comment: I've done some testing now, everything seems to be working smoothly, no unexpected behaviour thus far.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you expect the .autocomplete elements to hide when body is clicked

```
$(document.body).addEvent('click', function() {
    $$('.autocomplete ul').addClass('hidden');
});
```

You add the 'hidden' class on document.body click, but when you click on the other .autocomplete input, the event does not bubble up to the body element, because you intentionally stop it from propagating in click event with this line

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

You may solve it by adding condition to click event, where hide all other .autocomplete elements, or add another handler for blur event, where you hide the element itself.

Comment: As part of the comments to the original question, it was mentioned trying the blur event, and that created a separate bug. However, with a bit of fiddling based on your suggestion, I managed to get it working by manually closing all autocomplete elements that weren't the one that was just opened. I'm sure this method probably isn't the fastest/last memory intensive method of getting it done, but that can be reworked/fixed later. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you click on an input , the event binded with other input will not get fired and hence the class will be not changed, you will have to check that is there is any other autocomplete opened in the document than you should close it. you can so this with one small check inside your click event.

```js
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  new autoComplete();
});
var autoComplete = new Class({
 options: {
  version:  '1.0',
  lastUpdate: '2016-06-27'
 },

 Implements: [Options,Events],
 initialize: function(options) {
  this.setOptions(options);
  
  $$('.autocomplete').each(function(acl) {
   acl.getChildren('ul li').each(function(li) {
    li.addEvent('click', function() {
     acl.getChildren('input[type=text]')[0].value = li.get('html');
     acl.getChildren('input[type=hidden]')[0].value = li.get('data-id');
     acl.getChildren('ul').addClass('hidden');
    });
   });
   
   acl.getChildren('input')[0].addEvents({
    click: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     
     var el = e.target;
     var val = el.value;
     var aul = el.getParent().getChildren('ul')[0];
     var str = '';
                    var allInput= document.getElementsByClassName(el.className);
                    for(var i =0 ;i<allInput.length; i++)
                    {
                       if(allInput[i].getParent().className=="autocomplete" && allInput[i] != el && allInput[i].getParent().getChildren('ul')[0].className != "hidden" )
                       {
                           allInput[i].getParent().getChildren('ul')  [0].className = 'hidden';
                       }
                    }
     
     aul.toggleClass('hidden');
     
     aul.getChildren().each(function(l) {
      str = l.get('html').toLowerCase();
      if (str.indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != 0) {
       l.addClass('hidden');
      } else {
       l.removeClass('hidden');
      }
     });
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     
     var el = e.target;
     var val = el.value;
     var aul = el.getParent().getChildren('ul')[0];
     var str = '';
     
     aul.removeClass('hidden');
     
     aul.getChildren().each(function(l) {
      str = l.get('html').toLowerCase();
      if (str.indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != 0) {
       l.addClass('hidden');
      } else {
       l.removeClass('hidden');
      }
     });
    }
   });
  });
  
  $(document.body).addEvent('click', function() {
   $$('.autocomplete ul').addClass('hidden');
  });
 }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
}

.autocomplete ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.autocomplete ul li {
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
}

.autocomplete ul li:first-child {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.autocomplete ul li:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools-core.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Drk:</label>
    <div class="autocomplete">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <input type="hidden" />
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li data-id="drk1-Nito">Nito</li>
        <li data-id="drk1-Seath">Seath</li>
        <li data-id="drk1-FourKings">Four Kings</li>
        <li data-id="drk1-BedofChaos">Bed of Chaos</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-TheRotten">The Rotten</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-DukesDearFreja">Duke's Dear Freja</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-OldIronKing">Old Iron King</li>
        <li data-id="drk2-LostSinner">Lost Sinner</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Yhorm">Yhorm</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Aldritch">Aldritch</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Abysswatcher">Abyss Watcher</li>
        <li data-id="drk3-Lothric">Lothric</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Bld:</label>
    <div class="autocomplete">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <input type="hidden" />
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li data-id="bld-ClericBeast">Cleric Beast</li>
        <li data-id="bld-FatherGascoigne">Father Gascoigne</li>
        <li data-id="bld-WitchesofHemwick">Witches of Hemwick</li>
        <li data-id="bld-VicarAmelia">Vicar Amelia</li>
        <li data-id="bld-ShadowsofYarhnam">Shadows of Yarhnam</li>
        <li data-id="bld-VacuousRom">Vacuous Rom</li>
        <li data-id="bld-TheOneReborn">The One Reborn</li>
        <li data-id="bld-Micolash">Micolash</li>
        <li data-id="bld-MergosWetnurse">Mergo's Wetnurse</li>
        <li data-id="bld-OldHunterGermaine">Old Hunter Germaine</li>
        <li data-id="bld-MoonPresence">Moon Presence</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```